# .Net Function call in SQL 2005

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am getting the following error when I execute a .Net Function in SQL 2005, any ideas?

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 A
>   .NET Framework error occurred during
>   execution of user defined routine or
>   aggregate 'Function1': 
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Net.WebPermission, System,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object
>   demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean isPermSet)    at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest..ctor(Uri
>   uri, ServicePoint servicePoint)    at
>   System.Net.HttpRequestCreator.Create(Uri
>   Uri)    at
>   System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri
>   requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)    at
>   System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri
>   requestUri)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebRequest(Uri
>   uri)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebRequest(Uri
>   uri)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.GetWebRequest(Uri
>   uri)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
>   SqlServerProject1.navision.NavisionLink.GetPONumber(String
>   Database)    at
>   UserDefinedFunctions.Function1()

Answer (score 2):

You are not creating the assembly with the appropriate permission set.  Your `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement should look something like this:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY ... WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS
```

This *should* allow you to make the web service call.  If that doesn't work, then you will have to set `PERMISSION_SET` to `UNSAFE`.

Answer (score 0):

it seem you don't have enough security access?

but would be easier if you could post the code related to that error

Answer (score 0):

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString Function1()
    {
        SqlServerProject1.navision.NavisionLink po = new SqlServerProject1.navision.NavisionLink();

```
    string test = Convert.ToString(po.GetPONumber("NavisionDev"));
    // Put your code here
    return new SqlString(test);
}
```

};

Comment: Please add this as an edit to the question, not as its own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some security Informations for running you .NET code on the SQLServer.

Pls refer to [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Managed_Code_in_SQL.aspx) to find the infos you will need.